# Detecting div height on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I am trying to detect the height of a div that I am loading content into. This div does not have a specified height, as I am loading pages into it and they themselves fill up the div in different amounts. I think the code I am using is not working.

The `#content div` is getting the correct height on `document load`, however I cannot get the height when the `load` event is clicked.

html:

```
<div id="select">
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a class="load" href="javascript:void(0)" id="p1">P1</a></li>
    <li><a class="load" href="javascript:void(0)" id="p2">P2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="spacer"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

css:

```
#content {
    left: 227px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 703px;
    padding: 0 0 100px 0;
    position: absolute;
}

#spacer {
    border-right: 2px solid #000000;
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 710px;
    width: 215px;
}
```

my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Load Initial Content
    $("#content").html('<ul><li>Loading Content...</li></ul>')
        .load("/content/" + "projects.php", null, function() {
            contentHeight = $("#content").height();
            selectHeight = $("#select").height();

            $("#content").height(contentHeight);
            $("#select").height(selectHeight);
            $("#spacer").height((contentHeight - selectHeight - 40) + "px")
                        .css({"top": selectHeight + 40 + "px" });
            });

    //Load content on click function
    $(".load").click(function(){
        loadName = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#content").html('<ul><li>Loading Content...</li></ul>')
                     .load("/content/" + loadName + ".php", null, function(){
                         contentHeight = $("#content").height();
                         selectHeight = $("#select").height();

                         $("#spacer").height(0);

                         if(selectHeight > contentHeight) {
                         $("#spacer").css({"display": "none"}); 
                         }else{

                         $("#spacer").css({"top": selectHeight + 40 + "px", "display": "block" })
                                     .height((contentHeight - selectHeight - 40) + "px");
                         return false;
                         }
                         });
    });
});
```

I am getting this in firebug on load:

```
<div id="select" style="height: 689px;"/>
<div id="spacer" style="height: 5461px; top: 729px;"/>
<div id="content" style="height: 6190px;"/>
```

Now if I click on say P2, the div with content height stays the same, even though the actual content inside the div is only 625px tall; so it is not getting switched.

Comment: What Browsers have you tested this on?

Answer (score 2):

```
//Get Content size after load
$("#content").bind("resize", function(){ 
                    $("#content").css({"height": $("#content").height()}); 
                    });
```

you're not adding the "px" to the end of the height value

```
//Get Content size after load
$("#content").bind("resize", function(){ 
                    $("#content").css({"height": $("#content").height() + "px"}); 
                    });
```

**EDIT follows**

got it working locally, you were missing parenthesis at the end of the height function in the click event:

```
$("#spacer").css({"height": $("#content").height() + "px"}); //added parenthesis enables the #spacer div to change height accordingly
```

hope this helps

Comment: Hey Wayne, that was my mistake, added the +"px" but it still will not function…

Comment: Without the px, what units would css normally assume? Ans: px.

Comment: nope! either way, when you assume you make an ass of u and me, from experience I've found its best not to let browsers "assume" anything

Comment: Mr. Austin has a point. How many browser rending engines exist today? - I'm pretty sure the answer is alot, they don't all follow the rules.

Comment: @Wayne: My main point was that this answer doesn't solve anything because "browsers" (implied generality) assume "px" (in general).  Whether its important to include the "px" or not was not the subject.  I agree its best to be explicit when talking to dumb computers but we developers have a propensity to talk to each other in the same explicit way and get upity when we see something which whilst in the common and general is true may not __always__ be true.  It can be quite tiresome.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: and the point I am making is that actually, some browsers, including FF3 will literally ignore a style rule of just "height:30" with out the px unit on the end, I have several times forgotten to add the px into css changes made through javascript and surprise surprise, after adding the + "px" on the end, it worked. Hell, Try it for yourself!

Comment: @Wayne: Thats great!  So adding "px" is clearly really important after all!!  That just really fantastic!!!  Pity it doesn't actually answer the question though. ;)

Comment: aww, and you still don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

Unless JQuery is being super clever (and it is clever but I don't think its this clever) you aren't getting a resize event because firefox (and probably Safari) only support the resize event on the window object.  IE does support the resize event on elements such as a DIV.

Hence you need a different approach:-

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#content").html('<ul><li>Loading Content...</li></ul>')
              .load("/content/" + "projects.php", null, function()
              {
                window.setTimeout(content_loaded, 0);
              });

  function content_loaded()
  { 
    $("#content").css({"height": $("#content").height() + "px"}); 
  }

  $("#spacer").css({"height": $("#content").height() + "px"});

  $(".load").click(function()
  {
    loadName = $(this).attr("id");

    $("#content").html('<ul><li>Loading Content...</li></ul>')
                 .load("/content/" + loadName + ".php", null, function()
                 {
                   window.setTimeout(content_loaded, 0); });
                 });

    $("#spacer").css({"height": $("#content").height + "px"});
  });
});
```

Note I use the setTimeout method here because IE often lags when sorting out width and height parameters when content has changed.  By using setTimeout it lets IE sort things out before the height and width properties are accessed.  You could choose to remove it and pass `content_loaded` directly as the callback parameter to the load method.

Comment: Rather than using the .css method just use .height method to change the height.  The JQuery .height method takes a parameter which tells it what height you want to set.  Try using .height(0) in the onclick. TBH I can't quite see why you want be setting the content type height at all, surely you just need to ensure the spacer height is set as the content height naturally changes with each content change.

Comment: Yeah that is what I am wanting to do, the spacer is an aesthetic component drawing a right hand border along the content, though its in another div all together. I am not really too sure how to go about that. It can be seen here:
http://www.samuelfarfsing.com/test.php

Comment: Thanks for the "Fx does not support resize on a div" - however the code I am looking at does not handle click well since the animation that expands the div is after the click. I will add the code to the end of the animation

Answer (score -1):

I like to use offsetheight to detect height when one is not set.